# FreeBSD serial port lock files

Tags: freebsd, serial-port

Does anyone know when in FreeBSD's boot process `/dev/ttyu*.init` and `/dev/ttyu*.lock` files are created?

In other words, are they created by the OS within its boot process, or are they created when I try to configure and then open a `/dev/ttyu*` serial port?

Note: I am using four serial ports on my machines (Nexcom 6100 and Nexcom 6210) as an instrumentation interface, not a terminal interface.

FreeBSD 13.0-RELEASE-p4 amd64

Thanks!

Comment: I can see both of the files on my server, and I never touch the serial ports.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks for checking. We see that also, after we commented-out our serial port config/create/read code. So, I guuess the OS creates these guys during/after the device and TTY layer creation. We're still sifting through the OS source code....

Answer (score 0):

The ttys are configured by `init(8)`. You might also want to read `tty(5)`.

If your serial port is a USB device, `devd` sends the relevant event when the device is probed. See `devd.conf(5)`